# Tensorflow - How to let a chatbot use a model already trained / Error while loading a model

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, chatbot

**EDIT 1**: Following the answer received by akshat, I used [this](http://cv-tricks.com/tensorflow-tutorial/save-restore-tensorflow-models-quick-complete-tutorial/) tutorial to load the model.
The code has been updated as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class Bot:

'''This class defines the routine of the bot'''

def __init__(self, presentation):

    '''The bot presents itself'''

    self.presentation = presentation
    print('')
    print(presentation)

def ask_question(self):

    '''This method defines how the bot asks questions'''

    print('')
    self.answer = str(input('Please enter your question: ')).split(' ')
    print('')
    print('Thank you for your question. Let me check..')

def answer_question(self):

    '''This method answer the user's questions'''

    print('')
    print(self.answer)

def load_model(self):
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('model.tflearn.meta')
        new_saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
        print(sess.run('w1:0'))

bot = Bot('Good morning, my Name is BotPy')
question = bot.ask_question()
answer = bot.answer_question()
model = bot.load_model()
```

Launching it the following traceback is received:

```
2018-07-29 08:28:14.622798: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
WARNING:tensorflow:The saved meta_graph is possibly from an older release:
'model_variables' collection should be of type 'byte_list', but instead is of type 'node_list'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/marco/PycharmProjects/chatBot/main.py", line 41, in <module>
    model = bot.load_model()
  File "/home/marco/PycharmProjects/chatBot/main.py", line 33, in load_model
    new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('model.tflearn.meta')
  File "/home/marco/PycharmProjects/chatBot/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1960, in import_meta_graph
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/marco/PycharmProjects/chatBot/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/meta_graph.py", line 790, in import_scoped_meta_graph
    ops.prepend_name_scope(value, scope_to_prepend_to_names))
  File "/home/marco/PycharmProjects/chatBot/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3613, in as_graph_element
    return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
  File "/home/marco/PycharmProjects/chatBot/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3673, in _as_graph_element_locked
    "graph." % repr(name))
KeyError: "The name 'Adam' refers to an Operation not in the graph."
```

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**: I am trying to build a chatbot.

Following [this](https://chatbotsmagazine.com/contextual-chat-bots-with-tensorflow-4391749d0077) tutorial, I already have a jupyter notebook solution that is working with a model already trained.

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
import numpy as np
import tflearn
import tensorflow as tf
import random
import json

  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
stemmer = LancasterStemmer()
with open('intents.json') as json_data:
    intents = json.load(json_data)

words = []
classes = []
documents = []
ignore_words = ['?']
# loop through each sentence in our intents patterns
for intent in intents['intents']:
    for pattern in intent['patterns']:
        # tokenize each word in the sentence
        w = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
        # add to our words list
        words.extend(w)
        # add to documents in our corpus
        documents.append((w, intent['tag']))
        # add to our classes list
        if intent['tag'] not in classes:
            classes.append(intent['tag'])

# stem and lower each word and remove duplicates
words = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in words if w not in ignore_words]
words = sorted(list(set(words)))

# remove duplicates
classes = sorted(list(set(classes)))

print (len(documents), "documents")
print (len(classes), "classes", classes)
print (len(words), "unique stemmed words", words)

20 documents
6 classes ['goodbye', 'greeting', 'hours', 'opentoday', 'payments', 'thanks']
32 unique stemmed words ["'s", 'acceiv', 'anyon', 'ar', 'bye', 'card', 'cash', 'credit', 'day', 'do', 'good', 'goodby', 'hello', 'help', 'hi', 'hour', 'how', 'is', 'lat', 'mastercard', 'on', 'op', 'see', 'tak', 'thank', 'that', 'ther', 'today', 'what', 'when', 'yo', 'you']

# create our training data
training = []
output = []
# create an empty array for our output
output_empty = [0] * len(classes)

# training set, bag of words for each sentence
for doc in documents:
    # initialize our bag of words
    bag = []
    # list of tokenized words for the pattern
    pattern_words = doc[0]
    # stem each word
    pattern_words = [stemmer.stem(word.lower()) for word in pattern_words]
    # create our bag of words array
    for w in words:
        bag.append(1) if w in pattern_words else bag.append(0)

    # output is a '0' for each tag and '1' for current tag
    output_row = list(output_empty)
    output_row[classes.index(doc[1])] = 1

    training.append([bag, output_row])

# shuffle our features and turn into np.array
random.shuffle(training)
training = np.array(training)

# create train and test lists
train_x = list(training[:,0])
train_y = list(training[:,1])
# reset underlying graph data
tf.reset_default_graph()
# Build neural network
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(train_x[0])])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, len(train_y[0]), activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net)

# Define model and setup tensorboard
model = tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_dir='tflearn_logs')
# Start training (apply gradient descent algorithm)
model.fit(train_x, train_y, n_epoch=1000, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
model.save('model.tflearn')
Training Step: 2999  | total loss: 0.01771 | time: 0.006s
| Adam | epoch: 1000 | loss: 0.01771 - acc: 0.9999 -- iter: 16/20
Training Step: 3000  | total loss: 0.01754 | time: 0.009s
| Adam | epoch: 1000 | loss: 0.01754 - acc: 1.0000 -- iter: 20/20
--
INFO:tensorflow:/home/marco/PycharmProjects/chatBot/model.tflearn is not in all_model_checkpoint_paths. Manually adding it.

# save all of our data structures
import pickle
pickle.dump( {'words':words, 'classes':classes, 'train_x':train_x, 'train_y':train_y}, open( "training_data", "wb" ) )
data = pickle.load( open( "training_data", "rb" ) )
words = data['words']
classes = data['classes']
train_x = data['train_x']
train_y = data['train_y']

# import our chat-bot intents file
import json
with open('intents.json') as json_data:
    intents = json.load(json_data)
# load our saved model
model.load('./model.tflearn')

INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from /home/marco/PycharmProjects/chatBot/model.tflearn

def clean_up_sentence(sentence):
    # tokenize the pattern
    sentence_words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
    # stem each word
    sentence_words = [stemmer.stem(word.lower()) for word in sentence_words]
    return sentence_words

# return bag of words array: 0 or 1 for each word in the bag that exists in the sentence
def bow(sentence, words, show_details=False):
    # tokenize the pattern
    sentence_words = clean_up_sentence(sentence)
    # bag of words
    bag = [0]*len(words)  
    for s in sentence_words:
        for i,w in enumerate(words):
            if w == s: 
                bag[i] = 1
                if show_details:
                    print ("found in bag: %s" % w)

    return(np.array(bag))
# create a data structure to hold user context
context = {}

ERROR_THRESHOLD = 0.25
def classify(sentence):
    # generate probabilities from the model
    results = model.predict([bow(sentence, words)])[0]
    # filter out predictions below a threshold
    results = [[i,r] for i,r in enumerate(results) if r>ERROR_THRESHOLD]
    # sort by strength of probability
    results.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    return_list = []
    for r in results:
        return_list.append((classes[r[0]], r[1]))
    # return tuple of intent and probability
    return return_list

def response(sentence, userID='123', show_details=False):
    results = classify(sentence)
    # if we have a classification then find the matching intent tag
    if results:
        # loop as long as there are matches to process
        while results:
            for i in intents['intents']:
                # find a tag matching the first result
                if i['tag'] == results[0][0]:
                    # set context for this intent if necessary
                    if 'context_set' in i:
                        if show_details: print ('context:', i['context_set'])
                        context[userID] = i['context_set']

                    # check if this intent is contextual and applies to this user's conversation
                    if not 'context_filter' in i or \
                        (userID in context and 'context_filter' in i and i['context_filter'] == context[userID]):
                        if show_details: print ('tag:', i['tag'])
                        # a random response from the intent
                        return print(random.choice(i['responses']))

            results.pop(0)
```

Example of output:

```
response('Hello')
>>Hi there, how can I help?

response('open')
>>Our hours are 9am-8pm every day
```

My goal is to structure the chatbot itself using object oriented programming (with a base structure I thought about below):

```
class Bot:

    '''This class defines the routine of the bot'''

    def __init__(self, presentation):

        '''The bot presents itself'''

        self.presentation = presentation
        print('')
        print(presentation)

    def ask_question(self):

        '''This method defines how the bot asks questions'''

        print('')
        self.answer = str(input('Please enter your question: ')).split(' ')
        print('')
        print('Thank you for your question. Let me check..')

    def answer_question(self):

        '''This method answer the user's questions'''

        print('')
        print(self.answer)

bot = Bot('Good morning, my Name is BotPy')
question = bot.ask_question()
answer = bot.answer_question()
```

My questions:

1. Do I have to train the model every time I launch the chatbot or I can call the model already trained from the directory?
2. If one of the two solutions above is correct, how may I implement the correct one?

Comment: Use concept of checkpoints , link to the tutorial - http://cv-tricks.com/tensorflow-tutorial/save-restore-tensorflow-models-quick-complete-tutorial/

Comment: Thank you for the answer Akshat. I tried to follow the tutorial but got a KeyError: "The name 'Adam' refers to an Operation not in the graph." I will update the question with more details.